# To check role from vm template

Tags: templates, liferay

I am using liferay,
how can I check if the user is guest from vm template?
I am looking for something like $is_signed_in , but saw from other posts that it can be used on template,also how can I get the end of the url,

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Liferay, default role for the user that is not logged-in is Guest, which you can check using `$themeDisplay.getUser().getDefaultUser()`. If the value is true, it means user is guest otherwise user is recognized member of the portal.

Likewise, `$is_signed_in` does the same inversely, it ensures if the user is logged-in (Member) or not (Guest).

You can use either for the purpose of identifying guest / member, as following:

```
#if($themeDisplay.getUser().getDefaultUser())
    <h1>Guest</h1>
#else
    <h1>Member</h1>
#end
```

OR

```
#if($is_signed_in)
    <h1>Member</h1>
#else
    <h1>Guest</h1>
#end
```

For friendlyURL (end of URL), you can get it using `$themeDisplay.getLayout().getFriendlyURL()` and use it in condition as following:

```
#if($themeDisplay.getLayout().getFriendlyURL() == "/home")
```

Comment: You can add these conditions anywhere in .vm file.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: some meta data, but it looks like it getting always true, even if I am getting back as member

Comment: Which condition is getting true always?

Comment: Looks like it's getting chaced  or something first time it works with condition, but when doing refresh with the login then still getting as guest

Comment: I don't think so, there shouldn't be any cache issue. I have tested it. Well, you can use $is_signed_in for similar purpose, as I have mentioned earlier.